# How to change property of class from another class

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy and I have ran into a problem. I have class "MainPanel" that contains four classes "Navigation", "Images", "Config" and "Information". What I want is when a button is pressed in "Navigation" class, then a current screen is changed with screen manager in "Information" class.

Here is my code:
Main.py:

```
class Navigation(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Information(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SlothFacts(Screen):
    pass

class KiwiFacts(Screen):
    pass

class MainPanel(GridLayout):
    pass

Builder.load_file("mainPanel.kv")

class Complex(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainPanel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Complex().run()
```

mainPanel.kv:

```
#:include navigation.kv
#:include images.kv
#:include config.kv
#:include information.kv

<MainPanel>:
    cols:2
    Navigation:
    Images:
    Config:
    Information:
```

Navigation.kv:

```
<Navigation>:
    Button:
        text:"Kiwi"
        size_hint:(.3, .2)
        pos_hint:{'x':.1, 'y':.25}
        #on_press: <--- Change screen to kiwi in Information class
```

Information.kv:

```
#: import  FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<Information>
    transition: FadeTransition()
    SlothFacts:
    KiwiFacts:

<SlothFacts>:
    name: "sloth"
    Label:
        text:"im sloth"

<KiwiFacts>:
    name: "kiwi"
    Label:
        text:"im kiwi"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `id` to your `ScreenManager` in the `mainPanel.kv` file like:

```
#:include navigation.kv
#:include images.kv
#:include config.kv
#:include information.kv

<MainPanel>:
    cols:2
    Navigation:
    Images:
    Config:
    Information:
        id: screenManager
```

Then, use it in your `Navigation.kv` file:

```
<Navigation>:
    Button:
        text:"Kiwi"
        size_hint:(.3, .2)
        pos_hint:{'x':.1, 'y':.25}
        #on_press: <--- Change screen to kiwi in Information class
        on_press: app.root.ids.screenManager.current='kiwi'
```